# Unable to convert my py file to exe (tried auto-py-to-exe and pyinstaller)

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I'm a new member, I did created some python software to automate my job as below coding,

```
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

# ------------------------------UI----------------------------------------------------

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Daily Job Automation")
window.minsize(width=500, height=300)

my_label = tk.Label(text="Daily Job Automation", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
my_label.pack()


# ------------------------------Function----------------------------------------------------
def setUp(self):
    self.oldFailsafeSetting = pg.FAILSAFE
    pg.FAILSAFE = False
    pg.moveTo(0, 0)  # make sure failsafe isn't triggered during this test
    pg.FAILSAFE = True


def Ctrl_C():
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.press('c')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')


def Ctrl_V():
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.press('v')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')


def Back_To_Windows():
    pg.keyDown('win')
    pg.press('d')
    pg.keyUp('win')


def Start_Automation():
    # Open SQL
    Back_To_Windows()
    pg.PAUSE = 0.2
    pg.leftClick(x=272, y=745)
    sleep(10)

    # Change company in SQL
    pg.leftClick(x=603, y=464)
    pg.typewrite('dne f')
    pg.press('enter')
    sleep(1)

    # Key in password
    pg.press('tab', presses=2)
    sleep(1)
    pg.typewrite('ss0214')
    pg.press('enter')

    # Open Customer Aging Report
    sleep(5)
    pg.keyDown('win')
    pg.press('up', presses=3)
    pg.keyUp('win')
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=176, y=45)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=227, y=327)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=471, y=306)
    sleep(15)
    # Open filter
    pg.rightClick(x=445, y=373)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=508, y=378)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=1301, y=694)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=457, y=510)
    sleep(8)
    pg.leftClick(x=654, y=126)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.press('a')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    pg.typewrite('sql')
    pg.press('down')
    pg.press('enter')
    sleep(2)
    pg.doubleClick(x=586, y=213)
    pg.leftClick(x=656, y=508)
    pg.rightClick(x=1273, y=653)
    pg.leftClick(x=1231, y=637)
    sleep(3)

    # Open BID file
    Back_To_Windows()
    pg.doubleClick(x=424, y=42)
    sleep(3)
    pg.keyDown('win')
    pg.press('up', presses=2)
    pg.keyUp('win')
    sleep(2)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.press('f')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    pg.typewrite('dne fwg')
    pg.press('enter')
    pg.press('esc')
    pg.press('down', presses=2)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Open Over 90 days and copy to BID
    pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
    pg.leftClick(x=1321, y=691)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=471, y=511)
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=604, y=249)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=659, y=515)
    sleep(3)
    pg.rightClick(x=1155, y=659)
    pg.leftClick(x=1171, y=645)
    pg.leftClick(x=959, y=744)
    pg.press('right', presses=2)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Open Supplier Aging and copy to BID
    pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
    pg.leftClick(x=231, y=33)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=320, y=327)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=587, y=247)
    sleep(15)
    pg.rightClick(x=370, y=375)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=434, y=372)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=1292, y=685)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=486, y=508)
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=584, y=271)
    pg.leftClick(x=669, y=510)
    pg.rightClick(x=1311, y=655)
    pg.leftClick(x=1241, y=644)
    pg.leftClick(x=950, y=743)
    pg.press('left')
    Ctrl_V()

    # Open SQL for DNE TTL
    pg.rightClick(x=270, y=748)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=195, y=641)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=603, y=460)
    pg.typewrite('dne t')
    pg.press('enter')
    pg.press('tab', presses=2)
    sleep(2)
    pg.typewrite('ss0214')
    pg.press('enter')

    # Open Customer Aging Report
    sleep(5)
    pg.keyDown('win')
    pg.press('up', presses=2)
    pg.keyUp('win')
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=176, y=45)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=227, y=327)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=471, y=306)
    sleep(15)
    # Open filter
    pg.rightClick(x=445, y=373)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=508, y=378)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=1301, y=694)
    sleep(5)
    pg.leftClick(x=457, y=510)
    sleep(8)
    pg.doubleClick(x=586, y=213)
    pg.leftClick(x=656, y=508)
    pg.rightClick(x=1273, y=653)
    pg.leftClick(x=1231, y=637)
    sleep(3)

    # Open BID
    pg.leftClick(x=961, y=752)
    pg.press('right', presses=2)
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Open Over 90 days and copy to BID
    pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=430, y=589)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=1321, y=691)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=471, y=511)
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=604, y=249)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=659, y=515)
    sleep(3)
    pg.rightClick(x=1155, y=659)
    pg.leftClick(x=1171, y=645)
    pg.leftClick(x=959, y=744)
    pg.press('right', presses=2)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Open Supplier Aging and copy to BID
    pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=430, y=589)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=231, y=33)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=320, y=327)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=587, y=247)
    sleep(15)
    pg.rightClick(x=370, y=375)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=434, y=372)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=1292, y=685)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=486, y=508)
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=584, y=271)
    pg.leftClick(x=669, y=510)
    pg.rightClick(x=1311, y=655)
    pg.leftClick(x=1241, y=644)
    pg.leftClick(x=950, y=743)
    pg.press('left')
    Ctrl_V()

    # Open Google Chrome tabs
    pg.leftClick(x=125, y=740)
    sleep(3)
    pg.keyDown('win')
    pg.press('up', presses=2)
    pg.keyUp('win')
    sleep(2)
    pg.rightClick(x=308, y=81)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=389, y=105)
    sleep(1)
    pg.rightClick(x=402, y=86)
    pg.leftClick(x=483, y=108)
    pg.press('enter')
    sleep(3)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('w')
    sleep(1)
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('enter')

    # Ask for the OTP
    pg.leftClick(x=631, y=437)
    pg.alert(text='Please enter OTP', title='OTP', button='ok')
    sleep(15)
    # Go to the BID tab
    pg.press('pagedown', presses=5)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=901, y=311)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=216, y=285)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=81, y=235)
    # Create new record
    sleep(1)

    # Copy and paste AR
    pg.leftClick(x=423, y=403)
    pg.leftClick(x=949, y=749)
    pg.leftClick(x=881, y=294)
    Ctrl_C()
    pg.leftClick(x=134, y=747)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Copy and paste AP
    pg.leftClick(x=390, y=407)
    pg.press('tab')
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=958, y=752)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_C()
    pg.leftClick(x=117, y=730)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Copy and paste over 90 days
    pg.leftClick(x=418, y=441)
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('tab', presses=2)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=962, y=749)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=127, y=745)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Copy AR collected to date
    pg.leftClick(x=950, y=741)
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_C()
    pg.leftClick(x=122, y=752)
    pg.leftClick(x=393, y=482)
    Ctrl_V()

    # Copy Customer fund
    pg.leftClick(x=376, y=606)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=952, y=745)
    pg.leftClick(x=975, y=348)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=127, y=750)
    pg.leftClick(x=376, y=606)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Key in amount into OD used
    pg.press('tab')
    pg.typewrite('400000')
    sleep(1)

    # Copy Company's fund
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=975, y=375)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.leftClick(x=376, y=686)
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy Total available fund
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=975, y=400)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.leftClick(x=376, y=686)
    pg.press('tab', presses=1)
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Key zero into Forecast column
    pg.press('tab')
    pg.press('0')
    pg.press('tab')
    pg.press('0')
    sleep(1)

    # Copy MBB DNE TTL
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=975, y=450)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # key in 0 into DNE TTL Dep
    pg.press('tab')
    pg.press('0')
    sleep(1)

    # Copy OCBC DNE TTL
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=975, y=475)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy OCBC DNE TTL USD
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=974, y=500)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy MBB DNE Forwarding
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=525)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy MBB OPT
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=550)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy OCBC OPT
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=575)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy OCBC SGD
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=600)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy MBB INT
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=625)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy MBB ABL
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=650)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy MBB CPW
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=675)
    sleep(1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Copy OCBC Wiz
    pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
    pg.leftClick(x=972, y=675)
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('down', presses=1)
    Ctrl_C()
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
    pg.press('tab')
    Ctrl_V()
    sleep(1)

    # Click Create
    pg.press('tab', presses=2)
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('space')

    # Create message box
    pg.alert(text='Done, please check', title='Completed Create BID record', button='OK')

    # Back to the desktop and go to SQL
    Back_To_Windows()
    pg.leftClick(x=270, y=748)
    pg.leftClick(x=174, y=668)

    # Open Customer Aging - Duty
    pg.leftClick(x=207, y=95)
    pg.leftClick(x=1320, y=689)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=485, y=509)
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=581, y=327)
    sleep(3)
    pg.leftClick(x=657, y=512)

    # Open Customer invoices tab
    pg.leftClick(x=174, y=36)
    pg.leftClick(x=223, y=93)
    sleep(15)
    pg.rightClick(x=538, y=120)
    pg.leftClick(x=630, y=687)
    pg.rightClick(x=13, y=162)
    pg.leftClick(x=76, y=228)
    pg.rightClick(x=81, y=160)
    pg.leftClick(x=139, y=226)
    pg.moveTo(x=133, y=125)
    pg.dragTo(38, 187, 1, button='left')
    sleep(2)
    pg.rightClick(x=245, y=163)
    pg.leftClick(x=310, y=202)
    pg.leftClick(x=460, y=510)
    sleep(2)
    pg.doubleClick(x=600, y=297)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=664, y=513)
    pg.rightClick(x=245, y=163)
    sleep(2)
    pg.moveTo(x=315, y=261)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=539, y=264)
    sleep(3)
    pg.typewrite('456')
    sleep(1)
    pg.press('enter')
    pg.press('y')

    # Go back to desktop
    Back_To_Windows()

    # Open 456 excel and copy
    pg.doubleClick(x=1086, y=627)
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=224, y=223)
    sleep(10)
    pg.keyDown('win')
    pg.press('up', presses=2)
    pg.keyUp('win')
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=547, y=212)
    sleep(3)
    pg.typewrite("=vlookup(A:A,'[CT CHECK & DND LIST CHECK.xlsm]CashTerm'!$A:$D,4,false)")
    pg.press('enter')
    sleep(3)
    pg.press('escape')
    Back_To_Windows()
    sleep(3)
    pg.doubleClick(x=332, y=448)
    sleep(1)
    pg.leftClick(x=963, y=749)
    pg.leftClick(x=953, y=653)
    pg.leftClick(x=428, y=217)
    sleep(1)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=147, y=11)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=429, y=355)
    sleep(2)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.press('a')
    pg.press('c')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    sleep(2)
    pg.press('enter')

    # Paste into Cash Balance excel
    pg.leftClick(x=961, y=740)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=1141, y=605)
    sleep(2)
    pg.leftClick(x=713, y=220)
    pg.keyDown('ctrl')
    pg.press('a')
    pg.press('v')
    pg.keyUp('ctrl')
    pg.alert(text='CT Check done', title='Cash Term Check', button='OK')
    sleep(2)


# Button

button = tk.Button(text="Start", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), command=Start_Automation, width=10, height=5)

button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Basically its very simple coding without all kind of defined functions due to want to easy in reading, but I tried to convert into executable file, it's failed and showed below message when converting,

```
PS C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Company details\Python\PYAUTOGUI> pyinstaller -F Daily_Job_Automation.py
1437 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.9
1438 INFO: Python: 3.8.8 (conda)
1438 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
1439 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Company details\Python\PYAUTOGUI\Daily_Job_Automation.spec
1441 INFO: UPX is not available.
1447 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Dropbox\\Company details\\Python\\PYAUTOGUI']
1936 INFO: checking Analysis
1936 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1936 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1942 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1953 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6186 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
6187 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib'
9535 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
9757 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
9771 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\User\anaconda3\python.exe
10008 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Company details\Python\PYAUTOGUI\Daily_Job_Automation.py
12450 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
12450 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
27423 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
34945 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
45688 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
52902 INFO: Processing module hooks...
52902 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-appdirs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
52907 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
52908 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
52912 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
53125 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
55107 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
55560 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
56562 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
56576 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
56593 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
56612 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbconvert.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
56709 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
56759 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
59379 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
59395 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-py.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
59637 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
59638 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
60619 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
61126 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
61630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-regex.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
61631 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py:369: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if path is not '' and not os.path.exists(path):
62317 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
64036 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64180 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64185 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64185 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64190 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64259 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 793, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Company details\Python\PYAUTOGUI\Daily_Job_Automation.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['Daily_Job_Automation.py'],
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 606, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-gevent.py", line 16, in <module>
    datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all(
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 1081, in collect_all
    hiddenimports = collect_submodules(package_name, filter=filter_submodules)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 564, in collect_submodules
    names = exec_statement(
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 91, in exec_statement
    return __exec_statement(statement, capture_stdout=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 75, in __exec_statement
    return __exec_python_cmd(cmd, capture_stdout=capture_stdout)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 66, in __exec_python_cmd
    txt = compat.exec_python(*cmd, env=pp_env)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 546, in exec_python
    return exec_command(*cmdargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 332, in exec_command
    out = proc.communicate(timeout=60)[0]
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1028, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1401, in _communicate
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, orig_timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '('C:\\Users\\User\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-c', '\nimport sys\nimport pkgutil\nimport traceback\n\n# ``pkgutil.walk_packages`` does not walk subpackages of zipped files per https://bugs.python.org/i
ssue14209.\n# This is a workaround.\ndef walk_packages(path=None, prefix=\'\', onerror=None):\n    def seen(p, m={}):\n        if p in m:\n            return True\n        m[p] = True\n\n    for importer, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_mo
dules(path, prefix):\n        if not name.startswith(prefix):\n            name = prefix + name\n        yield importer, name, ispkg\n\n        if ispkg:\n            try:\n                __import__(name)\n            except ImportErr
or:\n                if onerror is not None:\n                    onerror(name)\n            except Exception:\n                if onerror is not None:\n                    onerror(name)\n                else:\n                    trac
eback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)\n                    print("collect_submodules: failed to import %r!" % name, file=sys.stderr)\n            else:\n                path = getattr(sys.modules[name], \'__path__\', None) or []\n\n
        # don\'t traverse path items we\'ve seen before\n                path = [p for p in path if not seen(p)]\n\n                # Use Py2 code here. It still works in Py3.\n                for item in walk_packages(path, name+\'.\'
, onerror):\n                    yield item\n                # This is the original Py3 code.\n                #yield from walk_packages(path, name+\'.\', onerror)\n\nfor module_loader, name, ispkg in walk_packages([\'C:\\\\Users\\\\Us
er\\\\anaconda3\\\\lib\\\\site-packages\\\\gevent\'], \'gevent.\'):\n    print(\'\\n$_pyi:\' + name + \'*\')\n')' timed out after 60 seconds
```

Appreciate if anyone here able to take sometimes to understand and gives some valuable opition on this, thank you.

Comment: **Exactly** what is the problem?

Comment: I tried to convert my python file to exe.file, but the error message appeared as above

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused if it can't find **additional files**. Follow the following steps to resolve it:

Go inside **`additional files`** and select `add folder`. Now go inside your **python folder** and inside `Lib/site-packages` select **pyautogui** folder
now do the same for adding **PyAutoGUI-0.9.xx** *(The version may be different.)*. Once done do the other things you want like adding icon, script etc. At last hit the Convert button. It may work.

Comment: If you got any error please inform me.

Comment: Hi Tanay, good day, really appreciate your answer, after I added the **pyautogui** and **PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.dist-info** into `additional files` as per your suggestion, it came out the same error message.

Comment: Most probably may be there is some error in your file selection please recheck.

Comment: Or you can try the terminal method mentioned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0i6DcnTGHo&list=PLGqQuTsW-t8w7q-A38PX1BrdRzI-TWJtp&index=4). If your problem is not solved please comment on the video so that I can reply you faster.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of **Windows defender** or any **antivirus** please disable it before building EXE. You can also try replacing your code with this:

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

try:
    # ------------------------------UI----------------------------------------------------

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Daily Job Automation")
    window.minsize(width=500, height=300)

    my_label = tk.Label(text="Daily Job Automation", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"))
    my_label.pack()


    # ------------------------------Function----------------------------------------------------
    def setUp(self):
        self.oldFailsafeSetting = pg.FAILSAFE
        pg.FAILSAFE = False
        pg.moveTo(0, 0)  # make sure failsafe isn't triggered during this test
        pg.FAILSAFE = True


    def Ctrl_C():
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.press('c')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')


    def Ctrl_V():
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.press('v')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')


    def Back_To_Windows():
        pg.keyDown('win')
        pg.press('d')
        pg.keyUp('win')


    def Start_Automation():
        # Open SQL
        Back_To_Windows()
        pg.PAUSE = 0.2
        pg.leftClick(x=272, y=745)
        sleep(10)

        # Change company in SQL
        pg.leftClick(x=603, y=464)
        pg.typewrite('dne f')
        pg.press('enter')
        sleep(1)

        # Key in password
        pg.press('tab', presses=2)
        sleep(1)
        pg.typewrite('ss0214')
        pg.press('enter')

        # Open Customer Aging Report
        sleep(5)
        pg.keyDown('win')
        pg.press('up', presses=3)
        pg.keyUp('win')
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=176, y=45)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=227, y=327)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=471, y=306)
        sleep(15)
        # Open filter
        pg.rightClick(x=445, y=373)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=508, y=378)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=1301, y=694)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=457, y=510)
        sleep(8)
        pg.leftClick(x=654, y=126)
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.press('a')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
        pg.typewrite('sql')
        pg.press('down')
        pg.press('enter')
        sleep(2)
        pg.doubleClick(x=586, y=213)
        pg.leftClick(x=656, y=508)
        pg.rightClick(x=1273, y=653)
        pg.leftClick(x=1231, y=637)
        sleep(3)

        # Open BID file
        Back_To_Windows()
        pg.doubleClick(x=424, y=42)
        sleep(3)
        pg.keyDown('win')
        pg.press('up', presses=2)
        pg.keyUp('win')
        sleep(2)
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.press('f')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
        pg.typewrite('dne fwg')
        pg.press('enter')
        pg.press('esc')
        pg.press('down', presses=2)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Open Over 90 days and copy to BID
        pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
        pg.leftClick(x=1321, y=691)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=471, y=511)
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=604, y=249)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=659, y=515)
        sleep(3)
        pg.rightClick(x=1155, y=659)
        pg.leftClick(x=1171, y=645)
        pg.leftClick(x=959, y=744)
        pg.press('right', presses=2)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Open Supplier Aging and copy to BID
        pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
        pg.leftClick(x=231, y=33)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=320, y=327)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=587, y=247)
        sleep(15)
        pg.rightClick(x=370, y=375)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=434, y=372)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=1292, y=685)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=486, y=508)
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=584, y=271)
        pg.leftClick(x=669, y=510)
        pg.rightClick(x=1311, y=655)
        pg.leftClick(x=1241, y=644)
        pg.leftClick(x=950, y=743)
        pg.press('left')
        Ctrl_V()

        # Open SQL for DNE TTL
        pg.rightClick(x=270, y=748)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=195, y=641)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=603, y=460)
        pg.typewrite('dne t')
        pg.press('enter')
        pg.press('tab', presses=2)
        sleep(2)
        pg.typewrite('ss0214')
        pg.press('enter')

        # Open Customer Aging Report
        sleep(5)
        pg.keyDown('win')
        pg.press('up', presses=2)
        pg.keyUp('win')
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=176, y=45)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=227, y=327)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=471, y=306)
        sleep(15)
        # Open filter
        pg.rightClick(x=445, y=373)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=508, y=378)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=1301, y=694)
        sleep(5)
        pg.leftClick(x=457, y=510)
        sleep(8)
        pg.doubleClick(x=586, y=213)
        pg.leftClick(x=656, y=508)
        pg.rightClick(x=1273, y=653)
        pg.leftClick(x=1231, y=637)
        sleep(3)

        # Open BID
        pg.leftClick(x=961, y=752)
        pg.press('right', presses=2)
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Open Over 90 days and copy to BID
        pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=430, y=589)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=1321, y=691)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=471, y=511)
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=604, y=249)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=659, y=515)
        sleep(3)
        pg.rightClick(x=1155, y=659)
        pg.leftClick(x=1171, y=645)
        pg.leftClick(x=959, y=744)
        pg.press('right', presses=2)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Open Supplier Aging and copy to BID
        pg.leftClick(x=279, y=751)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=430, y=589)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=231, y=33)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=320, y=327)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=587, y=247)
        sleep(15)
        pg.rightClick(x=370, y=375)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=434, y=372)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=1292, y=685)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=486, y=508)
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=584, y=271)
        pg.leftClick(x=669, y=510)
        pg.rightClick(x=1311, y=655)
        pg.leftClick(x=1241, y=644)
        pg.leftClick(x=950, y=743)
        pg.press('left')
        Ctrl_V()

        # Open Google Chrome tabs
        pg.leftClick(x=125, y=740)
        sleep(3)
        pg.keyDown('win')
        pg.press('up', presses=2)
        pg.keyUp('win')
        sleep(2)
        pg.rightClick(x=308, y=81)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=389, y=105)
        sleep(1)
        pg.rightClick(x=402, y=86)
        pg.leftClick(x=483, y=108)
        pg.press('enter')
        sleep(3)
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('w')
        sleep(1)
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('enter')

        # Ask for the OTP
        pg.leftClick(x=631, y=437)
        pg.alert(text='Please enter OTP', title='OTP', button='ok')
        sleep(15)
        # Go to the BID tab
        pg.press('pagedown', presses=5)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=901, y=311)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=216, y=285)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=81, y=235)
        # Create new record
        sleep(1)

        # Copy and paste AR
        pg.leftClick(x=423, y=403)
        pg.leftClick(x=949, y=749)
        pg.leftClick(x=881, y=294)
        Ctrl_C()
        pg.leftClick(x=134, y=747)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Copy and paste AP
        pg.leftClick(x=390, y=407)
        pg.press('tab')
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=958, y=752)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_C()
        pg.leftClick(x=117, y=730)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Copy and paste over 90 days
        pg.leftClick(x=418, y=441)
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('tab', presses=2)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=962, y=749)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=127, y=745)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Copy AR collected to date
        pg.leftClick(x=950, y=741)
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_C()
        pg.leftClick(x=122, y=752)
        pg.leftClick(x=393, y=482)
        Ctrl_V()

        # Copy Customer fund
        pg.leftClick(x=376, y=606)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=952, y=745)
        pg.leftClick(x=975, y=348)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=127, y=750)
        pg.leftClick(x=376, y=606)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Key in amount into OD used
        pg.press('tab')
        pg.typewrite('400000')
        sleep(1)

        # Copy Company's fund
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=975, y=375)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.leftClick(x=376, y=686)
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy Total available fund
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=975, y=400)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.leftClick(x=376, y=686)
        pg.press('tab', presses=1)
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Key zero into Forecast column
        pg.press('tab')
        pg.press('0')
        pg.press('tab')
        pg.press('0')
        sleep(1)

        # Copy MBB DNE TTL
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=975, y=450)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # key in 0 into DNE TTL Dep
        pg.press('tab')
        pg.press('0')
        sleep(1)

        # Copy OCBC DNE TTL
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=975, y=475)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy OCBC DNE TTL USD
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=974, y=500)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy MBB DNE Forwarding
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=525)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy MBB OPT
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=550)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy OCBC OPT
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=575)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy OCBC SGD
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=600)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy MBB INT
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=625)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy MBB ABL
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=650)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy MBB CPW
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=675)
        sleep(1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Copy OCBC Wiz
        pg.leftClick(x=951, y=740)
        pg.leftClick(x=972, y=675)
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('down', presses=1)
        Ctrl_C()
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=129, y=743)
        pg.press('tab')
        Ctrl_V()
        sleep(1)

        # Click Create
        pg.press('tab', presses=2)
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('space')

        # Create message box
        pg.alert(text='Done, please check', title='Completed Create BID record', button='OK')

        # Back to the desktop and go to SQL
        Back_To_Windows()
        pg.leftClick(x=270, y=748)
        pg.leftClick(x=174, y=668)

        # Open Customer Aging - Duty
        pg.leftClick(x=207, y=95)
        pg.leftClick(x=1320, y=689)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=485, y=509)
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=581, y=327)
        sleep(3)
        pg.leftClick(x=657, y=512)

        # Open Customer invoices tab
        pg.leftClick(x=174, y=36)
        pg.leftClick(x=223, y=93)
        sleep(15)
        pg.rightClick(x=538, y=120)
        pg.leftClick(x=630, y=687)
        pg.rightClick(x=13, y=162)
        pg.leftClick(x=76, y=228)
        pg.rightClick(x=81, y=160)
        pg.leftClick(x=139, y=226)
        pg.moveTo(x=133, y=125)
        pg.dragTo(38, 187, 1, button='left')
        sleep(2)
        pg.rightClick(x=245, y=163)
        pg.leftClick(x=310, y=202)
        pg.leftClick(x=460, y=510)
        sleep(2)
        pg.doubleClick(x=600, y=297)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=664, y=513)
        pg.rightClick(x=245, y=163)
        sleep(2)
        pg.moveTo(x=315, y=261)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=539, y=264)
        sleep(3)
        pg.typewrite('456')
        sleep(1)
        pg.press('enter')
        pg.press('y')

        # Go back to desktop
        Back_To_Windows()

        # Open 456 excel and copy
        pg.doubleClick(x=1086, y=627)
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=224, y=223)
        sleep(10)
        pg.keyDown('win')
        pg.press('up', presses=2)
        pg.keyUp('win')
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=547, y=212)
        sleep(3)
        pg.typewrite("=vlookup(A:A,'[CT CHECK & DND LIST CHECK.xlsm]CashTerm'!$A:$D,4,false)")
        pg.press('enter')
        sleep(3)
        pg.press('escape')
        Back_To_Windows()
        sleep(3)
        pg.doubleClick(x=332, y=448)
        sleep(1)
        pg.leftClick(x=963, y=749)
        pg.leftClick(x=953, y=653)
        pg.leftClick(x=428, y=217)
        sleep(1)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=147, y=11)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=429, y=355)
        sleep(2)
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.press('a')
        pg.press('c')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
        sleep(2)
        pg.press('enter')

        # Paste into Cash Balance excel
        pg.leftClick(x=961, y=740)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=1141, y=605)
        sleep(2)
        pg.leftClick(x=713, y=220)
        pg.keyDown('ctrl')
        pg.press('a')
        pg.press('v')
        pg.keyUp('ctrl')
        pg.alert(text='CT Check done', title='Cash Term Check', button='OK')
        sleep(2)


    # Button

    button = tk.Button(text="Start", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), command=Start_Automation, width=10, height=5)

    button.pack()

    window.mainloop()
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    pass
```